# Which is the frame used by Gmapping for the camera topic?

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

My robot always end up to loose himself "Deleting nodes..." and I suspect a problem with Gmapping.

**I would like to know how to determine which is the frame used by Gmapping for the camera topic.** Documentation says :

> Required tf Transforms

> <the frame attached to incoming scans> → base_link"

But how do I know what frame is attached to a particular topic?

I use an Asus Xtion and the package Depth Image to Laserscan.

Many thanks :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232159/which-is-the-frame-used-by-gmapping-for-the-camera-topic?/) by [Pandaii](https://answers.ros.org/users/22679/pandaii/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `frame_id` field in the header for each message indicates which frame the data is attached to.

You can see the header as part of the output from `rostopic echo /topic`, or if you want to see just the header on /topic, you can use `rostopic echo /topic/header`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: run `rosrun tf view_frames` and it will show you the transform tree.

Long answer: Gmapping provides /map-->/odom. You need to provide /odom-->/base_link-->/laser (or whatever you call it). Depthimage_to_laserscan has a parameter that allows you to set the name of the sensor frame. If you leave it blank it defaults to camera_depth_frame. I have not used the openni2 package before, which I am assuming you are using to run the Xtion, but if you run `rosrun tf view_frames` you can see the transform tree. Chances are, openni2 gives you /camera-->/camera_depth_frame and /camera-->/camera_rgb_frame, or something similar. You will need to make a static transform from /base_link-->/camera.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pandaii](https://answers.ros.org/users/22679/pandaii/) on 2016-04-18**:
Thanks, I did that but I doubt that the transform provided by default by openni fits the measurements of the Xtion camera. I wanted to bypass these default transforms to see if it would solve my "scan matching issues"...

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-04-18**:
If you want to make your own transform tree then you can take direct measurements on the camera and use a static transform publisher.